# trying to execute NetezzaSQL odbc vi aunixODBC

Tags: python, redhat, pyodbc, netezza, unixodbc

I am trying to execute Netezza connections using pyodbc thought presumably is unixODBC on a RedHat 7 box.

I am unable to do so.

I have netezza loaded on `/usr/local/nz` as normal.  when attempting to open a connection.

here's the connection string:

```
Connection=Driver={NetezzaSQL};servername=DEVDBSERVER01;port=5480;database=DEV;username=<<USER>>;password=<<PASSWORD>>
```

contents of odbcinst.ini:

```
[NetezzaSQL]
Driver           = /usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so
Setup            = /usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so
APILevel         = 1
ConnectFunctions = YYN
Description      = IBM Netezza ODBC driver
DriverODBCVer    = 03.51
DebugLogging     = false
LogPath          = /tmp
UnicodeTranslationOption = utf8
CharacterTranslationOption = all
PreFetch         = 256
Socket           = 16384
```

the error is something I"m not understanding:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
Exception ignored in: <bound method dbapi.__del__ of <modules.database.dbapi object at 0x7f6a31b08e80>>
```

if I put the file `/usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so` in a prompt, and hit return, it finds it no problem.

What am i missing here?
Thanks!

UPDATE #1...output of `ldd /usr/local/nz/lib/ibnzsqlodbc3.so`

```
ldd /usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77d0000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf7713000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76f8000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf76f3000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0xf76dc000)
        libssl.so.10 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libssl.so.10 (0xf7678000)
        libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libcrypto.so.10 (0xf74c5000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0xf741f000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7254000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77d1000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0xf7219000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => not found
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0xf71e9000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0xf71d0000)
        libcom_err.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib/../lib/libcom_err.so.3 (0xf71cd000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/local/nz/lib/../lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0xf71c4000)
```

update #2:
New ldd output:

```
ldd /usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77b0000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf76f2000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76d7000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf76d2000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0xf76bb000)
        libssl.so.10 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libssl.so.10 (0xf7657000)
        libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libcrypto.so.10 (0xf74a4000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0xf73fe000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7233000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77b1000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0xf71f8000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0xf71f2000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0xf71c3000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0xf71aa000)
        libcom_err.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libcom_err.so.3 (0xf71a7000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/local/nz/lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0xf719e000)
```

more info:
uname -a

`Linux <<hostname>> 3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 13 18:39:59 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

nzsql --version

```
nzsql (IBM Netezza SQL) Release 7.2.1.7-P2 [Build 27]
contains history support
```

## UPDATE #3 - shift to NZ 64-bit

```
 ldd /usr/local/nz/lib64/libnzodbc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcb6310000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0566d66000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0566a64000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0566848000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0566644000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f056635b000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f056614b000)
        libcom_err.so.3 => not found
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f0565f18000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0567578000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f0565d14000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f0565b10000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f05658f7000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f05656d0000)
        libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f056546e000)
```

same response:

```
[[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/nz/lib64/libnzodbc.so' : file not found]
```

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the output from `ldd /usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so`

Comment: updated as requested.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`libcom_err.so.2 => not found` might be the reason of the problem.

As a workaround try to copy that lib from nz directory (driver or kit) into /lib. Alternatively you can try to install 32-bit libcom_err package.

```
# rpm -qf /lib/libcom_err.so.2
libcom_err-1.41.12-24.el6.i686
```

I am able to reproduce something similar when I install 32 bit client on 64 bit system. When I switch to 64 client libs it starts to work.

```
[root@tsekmanrhel771 ~]# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/nz/lib64:/usr/local/unixODBC/lib
[root@tsekmanrhel771 ~]# /usr/local/unixODBC/bin/isql -v NZSQL
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
...
```

Comment: `libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0xf71f2000)` is now being loaded, so there is a small change here. What is the error you are getting now?

Comment: can you post `uname -a` output and also NPS client version?

Comment: isql from unixODBC does not work for me in a similar way

```[tsekman@tsekmanrhel771 ~]$ cd /usr/local/unixODBC/bin
[tsekman@tsekmanrhel771 bin]$ ./isql -v NZSQL
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/nz/lib/libnzodbc.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Comment: thanks!  I added the new information to the question.

Comment: thank you, your system is 64 bit, I'd recommend to try with linux64 client

Comment: I thought so too, so I decided to try that.  same issue...can't find libraries.added ldd and attempt output.

Comment: in the 3rd ldd output there is this error - `libcom_err.so.3 => not found`
I had the same in my system. This library is in `/usr/local/nz/lib64`. This is why I have added nz lib64 to the load lib path env variable - `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/nz/lib64:/usr/local/unixODBC/lib`

Comment: we were so close.  this did it `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/nz/lib64`  once this was in place, it all snapped.

Comment: you got me there.  thanks for listening.  my last comment was teh issue.  needed to add `/lib64` to the front of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH after satisfying the requirements.